# ¿Cómo colocar Background en Angular?

Tags: angular

Quisiera saber como puedo poner una imagen como background de un componente en Angular lo intente usando un background en el body de su css pero no me funciono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes asignarle la propiedad `background` con la directiva `ngStyle` que es la manera que usa `Angular` para modificar los estilos de los elementos, seria algo asi:

```
<div class="image" style="height: 100vh;width:100vw;" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-4.jpg) no-repeat 0 0'}"></div>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: si me sirvio Gracias solo una consulta mas para que ocipe todo el espacio que debo hacer?

Comment: debes añadirle  'background-size':'cover' a 'ngStyle' a continuacion de 'background...' separado con una coma. ([ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(TU_IMAGEN) no-repeat 0 0','background-size':'cover'})

Answer (score 0):

Ponle una clase a tu contenedor y en el css del componente define el background en ese selector.

ejemplo:

.wrapperCard {

background-color: red;

}